# AngularJS sharing resources across pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is a simplified form of the app I want to make but I'm not sure whether AngularJS is well-suited for it.

Page A displays:
1) a big countdown timer
2) a button to reset the countdown time
3) a link to open another Page A in a new window/tab

The idea is you can have multiple Page A's open in different tabs, and the countdown time displayed across them all are synced (ie bound to the same resource instance). Clicking the button to reset countdown time from any Page A will reset all of their countdown times. Looking to avoid using cookies or persistent storage.

Could someone show an example of the best way to do this with AngularJS?

Thanks very much.

EDIT: I know AngularJS is meant for single page apps. What I'm essentially asking is whether there is a way to give the illusion of a multi-page app, if that makes sense. And for the real trick: is there a way to retain timer syncing even if a Page A is reloaded?

Comment: It seems like you're missing the point of an AngularJS app. It's meant to act as a 1-page app. Once another page is opened in another tab, it ceases to follow that main rule. If everything is opened inside one window, then yes you can use $broadcast or $emit to do what you want.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper what is wrong with opening an SPA in multiple windows? Ray - can use postMessage API to communicate and pass data between windows, or websockets to keep real time sychronization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion.

You can create a service MultiPageDataProvider and use websockets https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket for synchronization. 
You must always pass data between controllers throught services. 
In this scenario you cannot use the rootScope for what you're trying to achieve (but this is off-topic).

This is the raw usage, you can encapsulate your solution in a service (MultiPageDataProvider).

```
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
  <section ng-controller="SomeController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="data in MyData.collection track by $index">
        {{ data }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script>
    angular.module('YOUR_APP', [
      'ngWebSocket' // you may also use 'angular-websocket' if you prefer
    ])
    //                          WebSocket works as well
    .factory('MyData', function($websocket) {
      // Open a WebSocket connection
      var dataStream = $websocket('wss://website.com/data');

      var collection = [];

      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
      });

      var methods = {
        collection: collection,
        get: function() {
          dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'get' }));
        }
      };

      return methods;
    })
    .controller('SomeController', function (MyData) {

      $scope.MyData = MyData;
    });
  </script>
```